# Wordpress plugin development, symlink not working

Tags: wordpress, macos, plugins, mamp, symlink

It used to works before maybe a year ago. now i'm trying to build new plugin using symlink. but wordpress not detecting that symlinked plugin.

i tried `ln -s /plugin-source/ /site/wp-content/plugins/plugin-name`
i've also tried using 'sudo ln'. but it's not showing in wordpress plugin. when i copy it directly it works fine. anyone know why symlinked plugin not detected by latest wordpress? Thanks!

Update

answer below works. in my case it was osx not letting wordpress to access symlinked pluging from my desktop (not sure what's reason). so i move it to htdoc directory and it worked fine.

Comment: How did you add your path? Did you use the relative path? If you can mention the plugin source path exactly the way you put it, that would help.

Comment: yes i did it like `ln -s ~/Desktop/wp_plugins/plugin-name/ /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site/wp-content/plugins/plugin-name`

Comment: it does create symlink in plugin directory but wordpress is not showing that plugin in admin plugin page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your comment, it seems to me that you have tried to add it as a relative path. You should be able to make it work using the absolute path.

`sudo ln -s /Users/username/Desktop/wp_plugins/plugin-name /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site/wp-content/plugins/plugin-name`

Replace `username` with your username. It should be able to fix your problem.

Comment: i tried it. but as before it creates symlink inside plugins directory.  but wordpress is not showing it in admin plugins.

Comment: it looks like wordpress can't access plugin symlink to my desktop( even sudo didn't help). i've move it to htdoc and now it works fine. not sure if OSX have made changes to file permissions. anyway thanks @Tharindu Pramuditha

Comment: Thanks for a second there I was like OMG it is not really supported! turns out the stupid macos's make alias GUI makes it relative